Decorate path with arrows at every N th node, or equally spaced along path
So I have a paths that were calculated using gnuplot and I would like to place arrows along the path every Nth node, such that they are roughly equally spaced along the path.
I have seen posts on here that show how to place arrows along every point in a path, but is there a simple way to place arrows only on some of the points?
Example code (left just a few paths):
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (12.500,8.750);
\gpcolor{rgb color={1.000,0.000,0.000}}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetdashtype{gp dt 2}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% A long path....
\draw[gp path] (5.808,4.081)--(5.706,4.084)--(5.681,4.085)--(5.555,4.089)--(5.429,4.095)%
  --(5.303,4.101)--(5.176,4.109)--(5.050,4.118)--(5.004,4.122)--(4.924,4.129)--(4.798,4.141)%
  --(4.671,4.156)--(4.645,4.160)--(4.545,4.173)--(4.419,4.193)--(4.400,4.197)--(4.293,4.217)%
  --(4.221,4.235)--(4.166,4.246)--(4.079,4.273)--(4.040,4.282)--(3.970,4.310)--(3.914,4.326)%
  --(3.888,4.348)--(3.788,4.383)--(3.785,4.386)--(3.788,4.386)--(3.914,4.388)--(4.040,4.388)%
  --(4.166,4.388)--(4.293,4.389)--(4.419,4.389)--(4.545,4.389)--(4.671,4.389)--(4.798,4.389)%
  --(4.924,4.389)--(5.050,4.389)--(5.176,4.389)--(5.303,4.389)--(5.429,4.389)--(5.555,4.389)%
  --(5.681,4.389)--(5.808,4.389)--(5.934,4.389)--(6.060,4.389)--(6.186,4.389)--(6.313,4.389)%
  --(6.439,4.389)--(6.565,4.389)--(6.691,4.389)--(6.818,4.389)--(6.944,4.389)--(7.070,4.389)%
  --(7.196,4.389)--(7.323,4.389)--(7.449,4.389)--(7.575,4.389)--(7.701,4.389)--(7.828,4.389)%
  --(7.954,4.389)--(8.080,4.389)--(8.206,4.389)--(8.333,4.388)--(8.459,4.388)--(8.585,4.388)%
  --(8.711,4.386)--(8.714,4.386)--(8.711,4.383)--(8.611,4.348)--(8.585,4.326)--(8.529,4.310)%
  --(8.459,4.282)--(8.420,4.273)--(8.333,4.246)--(8.278,4.235)--(8.206,4.217)--(8.099,4.197)%
  --(8.080,4.193)--(7.954,4.173)--(7.854,4.160)--(7.828,4.156)--(7.701,4.141)--(7.575,4.129)%
  --(7.495,4.122)--(7.449,4.118)--(7.323,4.109)--(7.196,4.101)--(7.070,4.095)--(6.944,4.089)%
  --(6.818,4.085)--(6.793,4.084)--(6.691,4.081)--(6.565,4.079)--(6.439,4.077)--(6.313,4.076)%
  --(6.186,4.076)--(6.060,4.077)--(5.934,4.079)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (12.499,8.152)--(12.483,8.154);
\draw[gp path] (0.000,8.152)--(0.016,8.154);
\draw[gp path] (7.828,3.889)--(7.701,3.863)--(7.676,3.858)--(7.575,3.839)--(7.453,3.820)%
  --(7.449,3.820)--(7.323,3.803)--(7.196,3.789)--(7.134,3.783)--(7.070,3.777)--(6.944,3.767)%
  --(6.818,3.758)--(6.691,3.752)--(6.565,3.747)--(6.466,3.745)--(6.439,3.744)--(6.313,3.743)%
  --(6.186,3.743)--(6.060,3.744)--(6.033,3.745)--(5.934,3.747)--(5.808,3.752)--(5.681,3.758)%
  --(5.555,3.767)--(5.429,3.777)--(5.365,3.783)--(5.303,3.789)--(5.176,3.803)--(5.050,3.820)%
  --(5.046,3.820)--(4.924,3.839)--(4.823,3.858)--(4.798,3.863)--(4.671,3.889)--(4.647,3.896)%
  --(4.545,3.921)--(4.505,3.933)--(4.419,3.958)--(4.385,3.971)--(4.293,4.003)--(4.280,4.009)%
  --(4.194,4.047)--(4.166,4.058)--(4.120,4.084)--(4.048,4.122)--(4.040,4.126)--(3.995,4.160)%
  --(3.942,4.197)--(3.914,4.214)--(3.897,4.235)--(3.865,4.273)--(3.832,4.310)--(3.788,4.346)%
  --(3.787,4.348)--(3.759,4.386)--(3.788,4.390)--(3.914,4.391)--(4.040,4.392)--(4.166,4.392)%
  --(4.293,4.392)--(4.419,4.392)--(4.545,4.392)--(4.671,4.392)--(4.798,4.392)--(4.924,4.392)%
  --(5.050,4.392)--(5.176,4.392)--(5.303,4.392)--(5.429,4.392)--(5.555,4.392)--(5.681,4.392)%
  --(5.808,4.392)--(5.934,4.392)--(6.060,4.392)--(6.186,4.392)--(6.313,4.392)--(6.439,4.392)%
  --(6.565,4.392)--(6.691,4.392)--(6.818,4.392)--(6.944,4.392)--(7.070,4.392)--(7.196,4.392)%
  --(7.323,4.392)--(7.449,4.392)--(7.575,4.392)--(7.701,4.392)--(7.828,4.392)--(7.954,4.392)%
  --(8.080,4.392)--(8.206,4.392)--(8.333,4.392)--(8.459,4.392)--(8.585,4.391)--(8.711,4.390)%
  --(8.740,4.386)--(8.712,4.348)--(8.711,4.346)--(8.667,4.310)--(8.634,4.273)--(8.602,4.235)%
  --(8.585,4.214)--(8.557,4.197)--(8.504,4.160)--(8.459,4.126)--(8.451,4.122)--(8.379,4.084)%
  --(8.333,4.058)--(8.305,4.047)--(8.219,4.009)--(8.206,4.003)--(8.114,3.971)--(8.080,3.958)%
  --(7.994,3.933)--(7.954,3.921)--(7.852,3.896)--cycle;
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{0.000cm}{0.655cm}}{\pgfpoint{12.499cm}{8.154cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}

This produces something that looks like this

And I would like to be able to make it look like this:

Although in this example I could use math to get the coordinates of certain locations along the path, I'd like to be able to decorate the Nth point of any path.

Have a look at section "50.6 Arbitrary Markings" of the tikz user manual

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

What do you meant with Nth point? Do you mean the coordinates? You might want to look into the show path construction decoration which gives you access to every path segment. You just need a counter than a draw an arrow tip …
